# nginx: remove path from proxy_pass on named location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have this nginx config to serve a rails app:

```
  location ^~ /api/ {
    alias /srv/www/rails/public/;
    try_files $uri @unicorn;
  }

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2007;
  }
```

I want to remove /api/ from the start of path before passing it to rails app, but since it's a named location I can't add "/" at the end of proxy_pass directive, how can I remove /api/ before passing request to rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
location @unicorn {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.